# why can't android gradle find junit? why isn't it searching for it in remote repositories?

Tags: android, gradle

why isn't it searching for it in remote repositories?

after all i have at the top of my gradle script `mavenCentral()`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"
```

and:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':lvl-licensing')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

result is:

```
$ ./gradlew --info build
.
.
.
Creating configuration testReleaseProvided.
Creating configuration testReleaseWearApp.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':myapp'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':myapp:_debugUnitTestCompile'.
   > Could not find junit:junit:4.12.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/home/myuser/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom
         file:/home/myuser/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar
         file:/home/myuser/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.pom
         file:/home/myuser/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar
     Required by:
         myapp-container:myapp:unspecified

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 7.023 secs
Stopped 0 compiler daemon(s).
```

Comment: Try using `jcenter()` and then `gradlew clean test`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I moved

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

out of sectoin

```
buildScript {
}
```

and added to section `buildScript {`

the `uri`

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
}
```

and it resolved it..

Comment: This solved the problem for me too. If anyone could tell _why_ that works, the explanation would be really appreciated.

Comment: it doesn't works to me, so i changed http tp https, so it works .

Answer (score 2):

gradle looks only in local places but not in `mavenCentral()` so i assume you either have no internetconnection to http://mavencentral.com or internetaccess is disabled.

does `ping mavencentral.com` work at the commandline?

does your `settings.gradle` contain this line which forbids gradle to use internet?

`startParameter.offline=true`

if you are using android studio: is settings/compiler/gradle/OfflineMode disabled?

I checked http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|junit|junit|4.12|jar that 'junit:junit:4.12' is available at mavencentral.com

Answer (score 1):

The solution described by @Jas worked for me. But, since I had trouble adjusting `build.gradle`, I decided to post an answer with the complete change. This is how my `build.gradle` looks like ath the end:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'    
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I set this in my Android studio project. and it worked for me.
Open Model Settings > Project > Default Library Repository > jcenter

Comment: What do you mean by "Open Model Settings", i.e. where is this on the menu?

Comment: Right click on your project.

Answer (score 0):

I could not set "Model Settings > Project > Default Library Repository > jcenter" as text field was some how non editable.

so added following in build.gradle and it solved my problem

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

This solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

You need **internet connection** *-at least first time-* to build project first time correctly (i really don't know why) !!!

so, to avoid that you may try download JUnit (required library) from [here](https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=junit/junit/4.12/junit-4.12.jar) and add it manually to your application into ~[YourAppFolder]\app\libs

then **rebuild** your app.